# What are not Nef Polyhedra?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, polyhedra, solid-geometry

I was reading about Nef Polyhedra, and I am trying to employ them to compute intersections.
From my understanding, a Nef Polyhedron can be seen as an object obtained from a finite set
of halfspaces.

I was wondering about some (easy?) example of objects that are not Nef Polyhedra: any suggestions?

Comment: A sphere? What kind of example are you looking for?

Comment: If you take a shape which is not convex then it cannot be a Nef Polyhedron. This is since halfplanes are convex, and intersections of convex regions is convex. A region is non-convex if you can find two points P,Q in the region so the segment PQ has at least one point *between* P and Q which fails to be in the region.

Comment: Well, can't I divide the convex shape into some subpolyhedron that are nef polyhedron and then obtain the original one? Can you propose a concrete figure as a counter example?

Comment: Ok, I see: "curved solids" are not Nef polyhedron. Any other example?

Comment: @coffeemath - Nef polyhedron can be non-convex, because it's a result of applying any finite sequence of Boolean operations to a finite set of halfspaces

Comment: @HEKTO So for example the union of $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$ which is the union of first, second and fourth quadrants is a Nef polyhedron? It isn't convex so if it is Nef it's a non-convex Nef... Did I get that right? [I thought only about intersections, apparently incorrectly.]

Comment: @coffeemath - yes, these three quadrants are an unbounded Nef polygon. If to consider intersections only you'll get a "convex polytope"